# Pointer Arithmetic: ++*ptr or *ptr++?

Tags: c, pointers, increment, dereference, operator-precedence

I am learning C language and quite confused the differences between `++*ptr` and `*ptr++`.

For example:

```
int x = 19;
int *ptr = &x;
```

I know `++*ptr` and `*ptr++` produce different results but I am not sure why is that?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

These statements produce different results because of the way in which the operators bind. In particular, the prefix `++` operator has the same precedence as `*`, and they associate right-to-left. Thus

```
++*ptr
```

is parsed as

```
++(*ptr)
```

meaning "increment the value pointed at by `ptr`,". On the other hand, the *postfix* `++` operator has higher precedence than the dereferrence operator `*`. Thefore

```
*ptr++
```

means

```
*(ptr++)
```

which means "increment `ptr` to go to the element after the one it points at, then dereference its old value" (since postfix `++` hands back the value the pointer used to have).

In the context you described, you probably want to write `++*ptr`, which would increment `x` indirectly through `ptr`.  Writing `*ptr++` would be dangerous because it would march `ptr` forward past `x`, and since `x` isn't part of an array the pointer would be dangling somewhere in memory (perhaps on top of itself!)

Hope this helps!

Comment: @templatetypedef If you would do printf("%d",*ptr++) .It would first print the value at the  location contained in ptr and then would increase ptr.

Comment: @Algorithmist- That's correct; I think my answer covers this.  Should I clarify it to make it more explicit?

Comment: @templatetypedef i think * and ++ have the same priority but since their associativity is from L to R this is happening.Do you mean the same when you say  ++ binds tighter than *.

Comment: @Algorithmist- Thanks for pointing that out; you're absolutely correct.  I will correct this.

Comment: `*ptr++` is equivalent to `*(ptr++)` equivalent to `*(ptr = ptr + sizeof(datatype))`

Comment: `*ptr++` will be useful , if your ptr is pointing to a string and you want to jump to next char in the string.

Comment: @instinct: No, the latter form is not even remotely equivalent to `*(ptr++)`.

Comment: @instinct Pointer arithmetic accomodates for the size of the pointed-to type, so `ptr + sizeof(datatype)` will actually move past `sizeof(datatype) * sizeof(datatype)` bytes.  See [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2abb8be0ecfed2f).  \[Note: Example is compiled as C instead of C++, due to `-xc` command-line option.\]

Comment: As @AnT suggested `ptr++` is the same as `ptr = ptr + 1` meaning `ptr` will jump to the next address (that is what adding 1 means in the context of pointers), in particular jump to an address that is `sizeof(datatype)` bytes away from the starting address. As @Justin Time - Reinstate Monica explained, something like `ptr = ptr + 3` would mean to jump to the address which is `3*sizeof(datatype)` bytes away. So indeed `ptr = ptr + sizeof(datatype)` means to jump to the address which is `sizeof(datatype) * sizeof(datatype)` bytes away

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer is not correct. It's not the case that the postfix `++` operator has the same precedence as dereference/indirection `*`. The prefix and postfix operators have different precedence, and only the *prefix* operator has the same precedence as dereference/indirection.

As the [precedence table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) shows, postfix `++` has a **higher** precedence than dereference/indirection `*`. So `*ptr++` gets evaluated as `*(ptr++)`. `ptr++` evaluates to the current value of `ptr`; it increments `ptr` only as a side effect. The value of the expression is the same as the current value of `ptr`.  So it won't have any effect on the value stored at the pointer. It will merely dereference the pointer (i.e., get the current value stored there, which is 19), then advance the pointer. In your example there is no defined value stored at the new position of `ptr`, so the pointer is pointing to garbage. Dereferencing it now would be dangerous.

Also as the table shows, prefix `++` has the same precedence as dereference/indirection `*`, but because of right-left associativity, it gets evaluated as `++(*ptr)`. This will first dereference the pointer (i.e., get the value stored at the address pointed to) and then increment that value. I.e., the value will now be 20.

The accepted answer is correct about the effects of the two, but the actual mechanism is different from the one given there.

Comment: This is a better answer than the selected one. Also, **Note 2** in [precedence table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) explains why `ptr++` evaluates to `ptr`.

Comment: `*ptr` returns an l-value. So `++*ptr` will absolutely modify the value of the object pointed by `ptr` (`x`).

Comment: Obligatory [Linux kernel demonstration](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/route.c#L208)

Comment: @giusti Oops you're right, of course. Sorry and thanks. Edited. Sleepy brain introduced an error into what was a perfectly accurate answer for several months.

Answer (score 4):

As templatetypedef says, but you should provide the parenthesis around `*ptr` to ensure the outcome. For instance, the following yields 1606415888 using GCC and 0 using CLang on my computer:

```
int x = 19;
int *ptr = &x;
printf("%d\n", *ptr++);
printf("%d\n", *ptr);
```

And you expected `x` to be 20. So use `(*ptr)++` instead.

Comment: don't you think first printf() should print 19