# sscanf statement stops the program

Tags: c, file, struct, fgets, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct urunler {
    int kod;
    char Ad[16];
    int stok;
    float fiyat;
};

void urunTara(struct urunler* inputs,int *amount);

int main()
{
    struct urunler Urun[50];
    int amount = 0;



    urunTara(Urun,&amount);
}

void urunTara(struct urunler *inputs,int *amount){
    char Temp[150];
    FILE *fPtr;
    fPtr = fopen("urunler.txt","r");
    if(fPtr == NULL){
        printf("File not found!");
    } else {
        while(!feof(fPtr)){
            fgets(Temp,100,fPtr);
            sscanf(Temp,"%d %s %d %f",&(inputs[*amount].kod),inputs[*amount].Ad,&(inputs[*amount].stok),&(inputs[*amount].fiyat));
            *amount++;
        }
    }

};
```

I am relatively new to C, and just started learning about structs. The text file contains these:

```
25 televizyon 1000 150.25
40 video 500 25.45
50 plazma 75 2300.50
76 dvd 20000 90.00
85 supurge 700 110.75
90 buzluk 250 10.00
95 teyp 1250 8.99
```

The problem i have here is with the sscanf. When i do all these inside the main function, it works great. However when i try to do it in the function urunTara something goes wrong with the sscanf statement and the program stops working. I successfully passed values to &(inputs[*amount].kod) and other adresses by using scanf. But can't understand what's the problem with this sscanf statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*amount++;
```

is similar to

```
*(amount++);
```

which means dereference `amount` and then increment `amount` to the element after that.
 Which is not correct.

Change **`*amount++;`** to **`(*amount)++;`**, which will increment the dereferenced  value.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481740/pointer-expressions-ptr-ptr-and-ptr) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209602/pointer-arithmetic-ptr-or-ptr) for more details

Comment: And here i thought the problem was with the sscanf. Thank you so much!